# How to convert words to links?

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink, words

I have a xml with two properties: word and link.
How can I replace the words on a text to a link using the xml information.
Ex.: 
XML

```
<word>dog</word>
<link>http://www.dog.com</link>
```

Text: The dog is nice.

Result: The [dog](http://www.dog.com/) is nice.

Results OK.

The problems:

1- If the text has the word **dogs** the result is incorret, because of "s".

2- I've tested doing a split by space on text to fix it, but if the word is composed like **new year** the result is incorret again.

Does anyone have any suggestions to do it and fix these problems (plural and compound words)?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you want to match dogs, or not? If yes, you are putting yourself in a lot of trouble, as you will soon discover that singular and plural forms are only the beginning... Nevertheless, could you explain your current implementation? Did you try to use regex matching?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Lucene.Net's contrib package  [Snowball](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/lucene.net/branches/Lucene.Net_2_9_4g/src/contrib/Snowball/) for stemming (`words`->`word` , `came`->`come` , `having`->`have` etc.). But you will still have troubles with compound words

Answer (score 0):

If you roll your own solution, I have had good success with the .NET pluralization capabilities:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.design.pluralizationservices.pluralizationservice.aspx

Essentially, you can pass a word in its plural form and receive a singular version and vice versa.

This could be fairly intensive depending on how often the content changed, i.e. this wouldn't be a good choice to search thousands of words in real time.

Assuming that you can pre-process/cache the results or that the source file is small, you could:

**Run Once**

- Identify all candidate words from the source file.
- Parse/split phrases and pass them through the pluralization libraries to determine their plural counterparts.
- Generate (and precompile) simple regular expressions to locate the words that you **do** want to match. For example, if you want to match "dog" but not "dogs" you could create a regex like `dog[^s]` which could then be executed against the text.

**Run Whenever a Search/Replace is Needed**

- Run your list of source expressions against the text in question. I would suggest ordering the expressions from shortest to longest (otherwise a short expression may replace a word that was just parsed by a longer expression).

Again, this would be processor intensive to run in real-time (most solutions will be). As always, if you are parsing HTML, you should use an HTML parser, not a regular expression. In this case, you might use a proper parser to locate all text nodes and then perform the search/replace on them.

An alternative solution would be to put the text and keyword list into a database and use SQL Server Full Text Indexing which tends to be pretty smart about these things and supports intelligent match predicates. You could even combine this with a CLR stored procedure to handle things that .NET excels at (like string parsing).

Regardless of the approach, this will not be an exact science.

Comment: Besides how to increase the search speed, you do not say anything about stemming.  gone->go, criteria->criterion, did->do etc.

Comment: @L.B - you are correct, the OP asked about pluralization and compound words...anything more than that will require a fairly sophisticated solution. I looked briefly at the product to which you linked and upvoted your answer.

Answer (score -1):

You're likely going to need a dictionary. Create a text file/XML file that contains both the singular and plural forms of the words you want. At runtime, load them into a `Dictionary<String, String>`. Then look up the value of `<word/>` in the dictionary and extract its singular value.